# AVG on same column by values in another column single sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, average

I want to find AVG on same column by values in different column single sql query.

```
table - question_rating
review_id
question_id
rating
```

- for each review there are multiple 16 questions and ratings.
- question_id values are 1 to 16.
- rating values are from 1 to 5.

I want to find avg of group of questions as

Desired output-

```
qustion_id     rating
-------------------------
g1               4.4
g2               3.7
g3               5.6
```

g1 is group of questions (1,3)
g2 is group of questions (2,6)
g3 is group of questions (7,8)
....g8

pseudo code-

```
 select (if(qustion=1 and question=3) as g1,
if(qustion=2 and question=6) as g2), ..
)avg(rating of respective group) from question_rating
```

I know it can be done by taking query separately but I want to know by single query.

Or any easy way to find such output by php,etc.

Comment: I don't understand what "I want to find AVG on same column by values in different column single sql query." means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make a table `question_groups`

```
question_id  group_id
q1          g1
q2          g2
q3          g1
q4          g3
q5          g3
q6          g2
```

And the select will be

```
select group_id, avg(rating)
from question_rating a
  join question_groups b on (a.question_id= b.question_id)
group by group_id
```

Comment: @SomnathMuluk - you specifically state that, for example, "Group 1" consists of Questions (1,3).  This answer suggests to put that association into another table, join on it and use a GROUP BY.  Unless there is something about your data that you did not explain, this certain does work.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  CASE question_id 
  WHEN 1 THEN 'g1'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'g1'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'g2'
  WHEN 4 THEN 'g2'
  ELSE 'others' END AS qGroup,
  AVG(rating) AS AvgRating
FROM question_rating
GROUP BY 
  CASE question_id 
  WHEN 1 THEN 'g1'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'g1'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'g2'
  WHEN 4 THEN 'g2'
  ELSE 'others' END
```

Comment: it is giving error as "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN question_id IN (1,2) THEN 'g1' "

Comment: @OlegDok CASE sintax is `CASE WHEN question=1 THEN result`

Comment: @FlorinGhita Its both, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-statement.html

Comment: I think is this: (read from case **expression**) `The return type of a CASE expression is the compatible aggregated type of all return values, but also depends on the context in which it is used. If used in a string context, the result is returned as a string. If used in a numeric context, the result is returned as a decimal, real, or integer value.`

Comment: @FlorinGhita g1, g2 and others ate comparatible 8-)

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I thought 1 and 'g1' are incompatible but this is not what the documentations says. It only says what type the result will have, based on all returned values. In this case I don't understand what is the error. The query looks fine.